# Formatting python string within a string

Tags: python, string-formatting, mysql-python

I am using Python MySQL connector, need to write a SQL query as:

```
update inventory set checked_out = 'n' where item = 'dongle'
```

All the items are placed in a Cursor from a previous execution, i'm using in a loop as :

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='mem_bug',user='root',password='July@2013')
for r in cursor :
   sql = "update inventory set checked_out = 'n' where item = {}".format(r[0])
   cursor.execute(sql)
   cnx.commit()
```

When SQL is formed it is formed as :

```
update inventory set checked_out = 'n' where item = dongle
```

Hence gives the error as :

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Unknown column 'dongle' in 'where clause'
```

How can I format string within the string to get my SQL rightly executed.

Comment: `where item = '{}'` may be? But it's almost always a bad idea to use `.format()` with SQL statement.

Comment: don't use format. Use parameters as explained in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add quotation mark and it seems the problem:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='mem_bug',user='root',password='July@2013')
for r in cursor :
   sql = "update inventory set checked_out = 'n' where item = '{}'".format(r[0])
   cursor.execute(sql)
   cnx.commit()
```